# simple responsive gallery for different aspect ratios

Tags: slider, gallery

I'm pulling my hair out looking for a way to display scale-able images with different aspect ratios. I found the Jssor Slider, but this might just be the most complex slider i've ever seen. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use $FillMode option.

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html